# What's the small gap between HTML inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

Given I have below HTML markup:

```
<div id="conatiner">
    <div id="b1" class="block">block 1</div>
    <div id="b2" class="block">block 2</div>
    <div id="b3" class="block">block 3</div>
</div>
```

and below CSS scripts:

```
div {
    outline: solid gray 1px;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

I expected the 3 blocks to be adjacent without any gaps. But unfortunately, the result shows small gaps between each other (in all browsers). 
[image]

I checked computed box-model with browser developer tools, I did not find any border, margin or padding value which may result in gaps. Then I am wondering what results in the gaps?

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YNmds/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White space in your HTML

Change this to:

```
<div id="conatiner">
    <div id="b1" class="block">block 1</div><div id="b2" class="block">block 2</div><div id="b3" class="block">block 3</div>
</div>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/jerryhuangme/95b39/

Comment: Thank your for your information. But why carriage return is translated to content in this case? By my understanding white space and control characters should be ignored in HTML source code, right?

Comment: @Shuping, it is very dependent on your editor and a known quirk in HTML. Or you can try this: http://www.odditysoftware.com/page-webtools16.htm   Most editors nowadays can remove whitespace (Sublime comes to mind).  Please accept answer if correct :)

Comment: @Shuping at least _spaces_ should not be ignored, otherwise you would have problems getting a space between this `<strong>something</strong> <em>else</em>`. For normal text (not link in `<pre>` or `<textarea>` contiguous white spaces and newlines are visually represented as one space.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.block {
   float: left;
   width:100px;
   background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used `display: inline-block`

You could do this:

```
div {
    outline: solid gray 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
    width:100px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
}
```

And keep your HTML as it is:

```
<div id="conatiner">
    <div id="b1" class="block">block 1</div>
    <div id="b2" class="block">block 2</div>
    <div id="b3" class="block">block 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution without outline size.

```css
div {

    outline: solid gray;

}
```